# change puppetdb dump location instead of /var/log/puppetdb

Tags: linux, puppet, puppetdb

I have seen a few `hprof` dumps of `puppetdb` indicating crashes. While I investigate that is there a way to  configure that dump location to be somewhere else. 
While I do have space constraints on /var/log - I don't want to just increase the /var/log partition.

Comment: I'm not sure about how puppet specifically handles it's dumps, but is it possible to just create a sym link at /var/log/puppetdb to point somewhere else?

Comment: Than you for your idea. I searched through the puppetlab but could not find something to configure hence posted it here if any knew. Sym link is one option (+1) that i might have to resort to but does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dump location is configured with the JAVA_ARGS variable provided in either `/etc/default/puppetdb` or `/etc/sysconfig/puppetdb` depending on your distro (Debian or RedHat respectively).

Ordinarily this will be set to something like this:

```
JAVA_ARGS=-Xmx192m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/log/puppetdb/puppetdb-oom.hprof -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom
```

You just need to reconfigure that -XX:HeapDumpPath setting to point wherever you prefer.

Comment: FWIW, if you wanted to chat about the heap OOM problems that spawned this question, I can help also.

Comment: Thank you @Ken Barber I should have guessed this was running on Java with the dump name  containing "hprof"